# Can anyone help identify this mystery integrated circuit?

Tags: identification, vintage

These were in a box belonging to my grandfather.

I don't know if it's relevant, but he worked at a navy yard. I'm guessing they're around 50 years old. Nothing comes up on google search.

I don't know if it's even considered an IC.

The ICs have the following markings:

CTS 7118 9-43 016-824-001

[image: CTS 7118 9-43 016-824-001]

Comment: Probably a resistor network or somesuch, rather than an IC

Comment: I'm sure we've had this question (with exact same photo before) - something like a year ago.

Comment: It would be impossible, I took this photo 2 days ago.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most likely a resistor network. This would be an uncommon color for an integrated circuit. CTS doesn't presently make integrated circuits, but they still make resistor networks. I can't decode the part number but their numbering system could have changed in 50 years.

7118 is the date code. It was manufactured in the 18th week of 1971.

https://www.ctscorp.com/connect_product_line/resistor-networks-rc-terminations/

Comment: The fact that they're jammed into styrofoam is a hint, too, although not a strong one.  There's a good chance that the part number is an in-house one for whoever bought them -- either because the parts had special processing, or because the purchaser wanted to obfuscate the specifications, or both.

Comment: Looks like they may be NATO stock numbers?

Answer (score 5):

I remember using that series of thick (or thin) film on ceramic resistor networks in the 80s. IIRC, the 016 may have indicated the network layout which was typically 7 series resistors or 13 parallel resistors with pin 14 common. The 824 may be the resistor code for 820k. I can't recall what the 001 indicated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they look like CTS resistor networks.
Use your ohmmeter to see if you can measure the resistance between the different pins to determine the resistances and how they are connected internally.[image]